# Spatie Laravel/Permission como leer en axios los permisos Vue Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

Hola estoy trabajando con laravel y axios, el tema que tengo un problema al asignar en el controlador de laravel permisos, y al ejecutarlo por axios me tira error 401 de que no tiene permisos y no me deja listar ni editar, en otras palabras el contenido de la pagina queda en blanco. ¿como podría axios leer los permisos?

*Controlador Laravel* Lugar donde le pongo restricciones con middleware para que pueda tomar los permisos.

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        //$this->authorize('view users', Site::class);
        return view('model.sites');
    }

    public function getSites(){
        //$this->authorize('view users', Site::class); //Funciona si esta comentado
        return $sites = Site::orderBy('id','asc')->get();
    }
```

*Ruta Laravel*

```
Route::get('/config','SiteController@getSites');

Route::resource('/config', 'SiteController',['except'=>['create','edit','destroy','show']]);
```

*Template de la tabla* se encuentra insertada directamente en blade y no realizado por compenentes.

```
<div id="config" class="iq-card-body">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Descripción</th>
                <th>Valor</th>
                <th>Acción</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="(site, item) in sites" :key="item">
                <td>@{{ site.name }}</td>
                <td>@{{ site.description }}</td>
                <td>@{{ site.value }}</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" v-on:click.prevent="editSite(site)">
                        <i class="ri-pencil-line"></i>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    @include('model.modal')
</div>

<script src="{{asset('js/config.js')}}"></script>
```

*Script axios, ya que no ocupo template vue, solo template blade*

```
const config = new Vue({
    el: '#config',
    created: function () {
        this.getConfig();
    },
    data() {
        return {
            sites: [],
            fillSite: { id: "", value: "", name: "" },
            errors: []
        };
    },
    methods: {
        getConfig: function () {
            var urlSite = "api/config";
            axios.get(urlSite).then(response => {
                this.sites = response.data;
            });
        },
        editSite: function (site) {
            this.fillSite.id = site.id;
            this.fillSite.name = site.name;
            this.fillSite.value = site.value;
            $('#editSite').modal('show');
        },
        updateSite: function (id) {
            var url = "config/" + id;
            axios.put(url, this.fillSite).then(response => {
                this.getConfig();
                this.fillSite = { id: "", value: "", name: "" };
                this.errors = [];
                $('#editSite').modal('hide');
                toastr.success('Sitio configurado con exito');
            }).catch(error => {
                this.errors = error.data
                toastr.error('Error al insertar el atributo');
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Este es el error que me manda teniendo permisos activados en el controlador.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si le quito la linea de permisos `$this->authorize('view users', Site::class);` me muestra sin problemas los datos y me ejecuta el metodo de getSites().

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: se necesita mas informacion para ayudar, como la ruta que utilizas y si dentro de dicha funcion puedes hacer un `dd(\Auth::user())` y te sale el usuario logueado o null.

Comment: @Shassain si me deja hacer un dd porque funciona el metodo, al igual si ingreso por URL me muestra en json los datos, pero al agregar la linea $this->authorize('view users', Site::class); me genera problemas de acceso

Comment: Podrias dotar el link de spatie laravel permission, es que no encuentro el codigo `$this->authorize`. ¿o como se inyecto la funcion authorize?

Comment: A traves de la BD con los roles y permisos si el Usuario posee el rol admin y ese admin tiene permiso a view user o view site se muestra la pagina.

Comment: Pues no conozco la librería en lo personal utilizo `zizaco/entrust`, por eso queria un link para leer la documentacion. de todas formas buena pregunta, +1.

Comment: @Shassain https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-permission/v3/introduction/ mi jefe me lo dio, pero tampoco sabe como hacer la conexión del axios con los permisos.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110748/discussion-between-shassain-and-alex-valenzuela).